# If you start a new character, will you get the preorder weapons again, or is it locked to your first character only?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

I think I made a mistake on my first character and would like to try a different start. Will a new character also start with all of the pre-order weapons/shields, or an I totally vanilla if I re-roll?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the game but do you have only 1 character/save slot? Otherwise just try maybe?

Comment: I'm at work, limited time to game, and you have to go through a tiresome character creation before you get the preorder weapons. Since I only get an hour or two max to play every other day, I'd like to know the time spend redoing character creation isn't a waste.

Comment: Can't say for sure, but it sounds silly to grant preorder items to a single character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I own the PS3 collector's edition with the additional items provided by the pre order, having said that I have 3 characters and they all had the pre order items available when they were created. I hope this helps you even though I know it's not the PC version.

***EDIT:*** As confirmed by @TonySniper mentioned in the comment below, this does apply to PC as well.

Comment: It applies to the PC version as well.